# Top: 50% Does Nothing

Tags: css

Trying to teach myself CSS. I'm trying to vertically center text but the examples online all use top:50% which does not work for me. Here's the css:

```
    .mainSidebar {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 5%;
            margin-top: 2rem;
            min-width: 25%;
            height: 9rem;
            background-color: rgb(97, 160, 108);
            color: #fff;
        }

        .sidebarContent {
            text-align: center;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            position: absolute;
        }

    <sidebar class="mainSidebar">
            <div class="sidebarContent">Useless info here!</div>
    </sidebar>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you trying to vertically center the text within your .mainSlidebar? if so, you need to add position: relative to your .mainSidebar.  As your code stands right now, you are centering your text 50% from the top of your browsers view port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this line on the style for `.mainSidebar`:

```
position: relative;
```

See it [on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49vbpndk/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Also you wrote:

```
 <sidebar class="mainSidebar">
        <div class="sidebarContent">Useless info here!</div>
</sidebar>
```

Sidebar is not a standard (semantic) HTML element. You didn't mention any framework or library being used so to fix this try using a div, nav or aside to accomplish what you are trying to do and then give it a class or id of sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

```
top:50%;
```

is from the webpage height. If you change the browser size, you can see it is moving up and down because it is `position:absolute;` which means it doesn't care where it belongs to.

If you make `display:relative;` you can control its position from the parent block.

check:

```css
.mainSidebar {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    min-width: 25%;
    height: 9rem;
    background-color: rgb(97, 160, 108);
    color: #fff;
}
.greenBlock {
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<sidebar class="mainSidebar">
    <div class="greenBlock">Useless info here!
    </div>
</sidebar>
```